# React Native: TextInput within Modal is immediately blurred after being focused on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am developing a React Native component such that there is a TextInput component within a Modal component, such that when the Modal appears, the user can type in the relevant text. I am using the KeyboardAwareScrollView library such that when the Keyboard appears it does not block the TextInput component.

However, on Android, as soon as the TextInput component is pressed and focused, it is blurred, such that the Keyboard pops up but immediately closes. Strangely, this issue does not happen on iOS.

Here are what I have tried/checked:

1. KeyboardAwareScrollView has been configured correctly according to the official [documentation](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view).
2. The issue persists even when I use KeyboardAvoidingView instead of KeyboardAwareScollView.
3. Swipe down gesture works correctly for the Modal component.
4. When I remove the Modal component, the issue stops happening, so it must be related to touch events handling between the Modal component and the TextInput component, but I don't know what exactly is happening. I also need to keep the Modal component because of design choices.
5. The issue, as I mentioned, does not happen at all in iOS, so this must be related to Android-specific factors.

Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue? Below is the part of the code I am using. (Excuse the inline stylings. I plan to optimize after resolving this):

```
const Input = props => {
  const setInputdate = props.setInputdate;

  const [input, setInput] = useState({comment: null, prepopulate:null});
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const onSwipeDown = () => {
    setInputdate(null);
  };

  return (
    <GestureRecognizer style={{flex: 1}} onSwipeDown={onSwipeDown}>
      <Modal
        visible={!(inputdate === null)}
        transparent={true}
        animationType="slide"
        >
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            alignSelf:'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', // Dark overlay color
            flexGrow:1
          }}
          extraHeight={10}
          enableOnAndroid={true}
          enableAutomaticScroll={(Platform.OS === 'ios')}
          >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{height:screenHeight-550,width:'100%'}}
            onPress={onSwipeDown}
          />
          <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignSelf:'center',
            alignContent:'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
          }}>
            <View
              style={{
                paddingLeft: 20,
                paddingRight: 20,
                height: 146,
                marginTop: 33,
                width: '100%',
              }}>
              <TextInput
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  padding:13,
                  paddingTop:13,
                  paddingBottom:13,
                  height: 80,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  marginTop: 12,
                  height: 119,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  fontSize:16,
                  textAlignVertical:'top'
                }}
                value={input.comment}
                multiline={true}
                placeholder='how are you feeling?'
                onChangeText={(value)=>{
                  setInput({...input, comment: value});
                }}
                onBlur={(event) => {
                  setInput({...input, comment: event.nativeEvent.text});
                  if (input.prepopulate) {
                    setActive(true);
                  }
              }}
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                paddingLeft: 22,
                paddingRight: 22,
                width: '90%',
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: active
                  ? 'rgba(80,80,80,1)'
                  : 'rgba(217,216,215,1)',
                height: 57,
                marginTop: 33,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
              disabled={!active}
              onPress={saveDateData}>
              {input.prepopulate?
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                Update
                </Text>
                :
                <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                Record
                </Text>
              }
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </Modal>
    </GestureRecognizer>
  );
};

const Screen = () => {
  /*
  Irrelevant code
  */

  return (
    /*
    Rest of the parent component
    */
    inputdate ? (
      <Input
        setInputdate={setInputdate}
      />
    ) : null
  )
}
```